# Why is the Arduino IDE ignoring my replacement start up code?

Tags: startup

I am trying to replace the standard startup code to save flash space.

I've put the new `startup.s` in my `core` directory and added the `-nostartfiles` parameter to the linker reciepe in my `platform.txt`.

When I compile with the IDE, it does not include my start code at all.

When I use Atmel Studio or a makefile, the code assembles and is included just fine.

How can I get the Arduino IDE to use my new start up code?

Comment: to which board package does this apply? I don't have an startup.S file in any of the many installed packages

Comment: @Juraj I am using a custom AVR board, but this applies to any board with an architecture that requires a startup file - which is all that I know of. The standard startup file is usually included as an already compiled `.o` file. For example, the AVR start code lives in the `hardware/tools/avr/lib` tree as `crtXXXX.o` where the subsirectory and the `XXXX` depends on the selected platform/board/chip/variant. This file is automagically included by the linker is `-nostartfiles` is not specified.

Comment: is it a bug in Arduino builder?

Comment: @Juraj I'd call it more of an "unexpected, undocumented, and undesirable behavior" than a bug. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino builder is case sensitive and will only see files that end in `.S` and not files that end in `.s`.

Renaming the new start up file to `startup.S` and then deleting the precomplied core archive fixed the problem.

Note that committing this change to git [slightly complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683458/how-do-i-commit-case-sensitive-only-filename-changes-in-git)!